# Lambda capture reference by copy and decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Consider the simple program:

```
int i = 0;
int& j = i;

auto lambda = [=]{
    std::cout << &j << std::endl; //odr-use j
};
```

According to [expr.prim.lambda], the closure member variable `j` should have type `int`:

> An entity is *captured by copy* if it is implicitly captured and the *capture-default* is `=` or if it is explicitly captured with a capture that is not of the form *& identifier* or *& identifier initializer*. For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members is unspecified. **The type of such a data member** is the type of the corresponding captured entity if the entity is not a reference to an object, **or the referenced type otherwise**.

So what I'm printing is the address of some `int` unrelated to the outer-scope `i` or `j`. This is all well and good. However, when I throw in `decltype`:

```
auto lambda = [j] {
    std::cout << &j << std::endl;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(j), int>::value, "!"); // error: !
};
```

That fails to compile because `decltype(j)` evaluates as `int&`. Why? `j` in that scope should refer to the data member, should it not?

As a related followup, if the lambda capture were instead an *init-capture* with `[j=j]{...}`, *then* clang would report `decltype(j)` as `int` and not `int&`. Why the difference?

Comment: init-capture with `[j=j]` means roughly `auto j = j` the left `j` is not a capture so it isn't surprising at all that it has different semantics. init-capture with `[j]` would be the equivalent you are looking for.

Comment: "should refer to the data member". Only when odr-used. Otherwise it refers to the original entity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way name lookup works inside lambda-expressions is a bit peculiar: *id-expressions* which refer to entities *captured by copy* are transformed from accesses to the captured entities to accesses to the stored data members of the closure type -- **but only if these accesses constitute *odr-uses***. Note that due to implicit capture, if there's no odr-use, there is possibly no such data member.

`decltype` does not constitute an odr-use, hence it will always refer to the captured entity (the original), not the data member (the copy).

C++11 [expr.prim.lamba]p17

> Every id-expression that is an *odr-use* of an entity captured by
>   copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data
>   member of the closure type.

and furthermore, p18 even displays this weird effect in an example:

> Every occurrence of `decltype((x))` where `x` is a possibly parenthesized
>   *id-expression* that names an entity of automatic storage duration is
>   treated as if `x` were transformed into an access to a corresponding
>   data member of the closure type that would have been declared if `x`
>   were an odr-use of the denoted entity. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> void f3() {
>     float x, &r = x;
>     [=] { // x and r are not captured (appearance in a decltype operand is not an odr-use)
>         decltype(x) y1;        // y1 has type float
>         decltype((x)) y2 = y1; // y2 has type float const& because this lambda
>                                // is not mutable and x is an lvalue
>         decltype(r) r1 = y1;   // r1 has type float& (transformation not considered)
>         decltype((r)) r2 = y2; // r2 has type float const&
>     };
> }
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

---

The C++14 *init-captures* are also considered *capture by copy*, since C++14 [expr.prim.lambda]p15

> An entity is *captured by copy* if it is implicitly captured and the
>   *capture-default* is `=` or if it is explicitly captured with a capture
>   that is not of the form `&` *identifier* or `&` *identifier initializer*.

However, as [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) has pointed out, they do not capture the entity they've been initialized with, but rather a "dummy variable" which is also used for type deduction [expr.prim.lambda]p11

> An *init-capture* behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a
>   variable of the form “`auto` init-capture `;`” whose declarative region is
>   the *lambda-expression*’s compound-statement [...]

The type deduction alters the type of this variable, e.g. `char const[N]` -> `char const*`, and the original entity might not even have a type, e.g. `[i = {1,2,3}]{}`.

Therefore, the *id-expression* `j` in the lambda `[j=j]{ decltype(j) x; }` refers to this dummy variable and its type is `int`, not `int&`.

Comment: I'd guess that it might be surprising if the types changed by adding an odr-use, so the two basic choices are: let `decltype` always refer to the original, or let it always refer to the type the copy would have. Note sure I like their solution, though.

Comment: I think you're right, but seems unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: `[j = j]` is a capture by copy, but it captures the `auto j` in `auto j = /* the int & */ j;` (yay for impossible-to-write-in-ordinary-C++-stuff), which is an `int`, rather than the `int &` j. See [expr.prim.lambda]/p11.

Comment: @T.C. I guess this actually makes sense. If you're explicitly *init-capturing*, then that variable is definitely going to be a member of the lambda. But otherwise, it won't be unless it's odr-used... So with unevaluated expressions we're making a best effort to now throw extra shit into the lambda?