# Why do these lambda captured values have different types?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer

Two int variables, one a reference, when captured by lambdas, differ in type in MSVC's c++20. Why?

Scott's technique to determine type at compile time produces expected results for c++14 and 17 but not for c++20. However, it seems this odd difference occurs in other compiles for earlier versions too.

Specifically, two ints, one a reference, when captured by either value or reference produce differing types. `int` and `int &`. Yet earlier versions produces expected types. When captured by value both were typed `int`. When captured by reference both were `int &`.

```
// Scott Meyer's compile time Type Deduction technique
template<typename T>
class TD;

int main()
{
    int i{ 1 };
    int& ri = i;

    [i, ri]() mutable {
        TD<decltype(i)> WhatAmI1;    // c++14, c++17 TD<int>, c++20 TD<int>
        TD<decltype(ri)> WhatAmI2;   // c++14, c++17 TD<int>, c++20 TD<int &>
    }();

    [&i, &ri]() mutable {
        TD<decltype(i)> WhatAmI3;    // c++14, c++17 TD<int&>, c++20 TD<int>
        TD<decltype(ri)> WhatAmI4;   // c++14, c++17 TD<int&>, c++20 TD<int &>
    }();
}
```

Exploring this further, the code produced is as expected and is the same for both captured values and captured references.

```
int main()
{
    int i{ 1 };
    int& ri = i;

    [i, ri]() mutable {
        i += 2;
        ri += 3;
    }();

    [&i, &ri]() {
        i += 2;
        ri += 3;
    }();
}

     [i, ri]() mutable {
         i += 2;
00007FF7F506187F 48 8B 85 E0 00 00 00 mov         rax,qword ptr [this]
00007FF7F5061886 8B 00                mov         eax,dword ptr [rax]
00007FF7F5061888 83 C0 02             add         eax,2
00007FF7F506188B 48 8B 8D E0 00 00 00 mov         rcx,qword ptr [this]
00007FF7F5061892 89 01                mov         dword ptr [rcx],eax
         ri += 3;
00007FF7F5061894 48 8B 85 E0 00 00 00 mov         rax,qword ptr [this]
00007FF7F506189B 8B 40 04             mov         eax,dword ptr [rax+4]
00007FF7F506189E 83 C0 03             add         eax,3
00007FF7F50618A1 48 8B 8D E0 00 00 00 mov         rcx,qword ptr [this]
00007FF7F50618A8 89 41 04             mov         dword ptr [rcx+4],eax



     [&i, &ri]() {
         i += 2;
00007FF7F506190F 48 8B 85 E0 00 00 00 mov         rax,qword ptr [this]
00007FF7F5061916 48 8B 00             mov         rax,qword ptr [rax]
00007FF7F5061919 8B 00                mov         eax,dword ptr [rax]
00007FF7F506191B 83 C0 02             add         eax,2
00007FF7F506191E 48 8B 8D E0 00 00 00 mov         rcx,qword ptr [this]
00007FF7F5061925 48 8B 09             mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx]
00007FF7F5061928 89 01                mov         dword ptr [rcx],eax
         ri += 3;
00007FF7F506192A 48 8B 85 E0 00 00 00 mov         rax,qword ptr [this]
00007FF7F5061931 48 8B 40 08          mov         rax,qword ptr [rax+8]
00007FF7F5061935 8B 00                mov         eax,dword ptr [rax]
00007FF7F5061937 83 C0 03             add         eax,3
00007FF7F506193A 48 8B 8D E0 00 00 00 mov         rcx,qword ptr [this]
00007FF7F5061941 48 8B 49 08          mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx+8]
00007FF7F5061945 89 01                mov         dword ptr [rcx],eax
     }();
```

Link to compiler explorer https://godbolt.org/z/oe9KPcWWv

Comment: I can only assume the old MSVC behavior to be a bug, which they decided to fix only in `/std:c++20`. `decltype` in this case refers to the original variable, not the capture (GCC and Clang agree, regardless of the standard revision). `decltype((x))` would refer to the capture, but it would also add `&` to the type, since those are all lvalues.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  But why would it refer to the original variable and not the captured variable? That's the one that's in scope, not the originals. And yes, the value categories have reference added to them in both cases. I haven't seen any operational issues, just the weird way they are declared.

Comment: `decltype` has special rules for variables (when you add a second set of parentheses, it falls back to its normal behavior). Normally the difference is that for variables it reports the type of the variable, while in general it adds fake `&` or `&&` or nothing to indicate value category ([expressions can't have reference types](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1), so no information is lost). But apparently one of the effects of the variable rules is that it ignores the captures and examines the original variables instead.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat. I understand what the extra parens do. But I'm not aware of any rule that says `decltype` would have special rules that ignore the local scope and use the outer scope. Makes no sense. The capture copies are completely distinct and local to the lambda. Why would `decltype` refer to the types the copies were made from? Is this some special deal that applies to lambdas?

Comment: Seems so, found a standard quote here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33854742/2752075

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894748 (the MSVC C++20 behavior is correct afaict).

Comment: @cigien example was a generic copy capture `[=]` so it makes some sense that `decltype` would reference the origjnal. Sort of anyway. I guess declaring specific captured values is similar.  Very strange behavior but consistent.

Comment: `[=]` and explicitly capturing a variable without `&` are both captures by copy, which the answer on the linked post mentions as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of Clang, GCC and MSVC in C++20 mode is correct for all standard versions supporting lambdas. `decltype(i)` and `decltype(ri)` yield the type of the named variables. It is not rewritten to refer to the members of the closure object, as would be the case for `decltype((ri))`. (see e.g. [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#capture-14) in C++17 draft N4659 handling this specifically)

Apparently MSVC's default behavior for standard modes before C++20 is non-conforming in how lambdas are handled. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-lambda?view=msvc-170) the flag `/Zc:lambda` must be given to handle lambdas standard-conforming. With this option MSVC produces the same result as in C++20 mode for C++17 and C++14 mode as well.

See for example [this bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/decltype-of-lambda-by-reference-capture-yields-inc/1173319) which was closed as not-a-bug with instruction to use this flag. Also note that it doesn't seem to be included in `/permissive-`.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know about that option and assumed /permissive- would have been sufficient to be standard compliant.

Comment: @doug So I thought as well. I just noticed it in [this related bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/decltype-of-lambda-by-reference-capture-yields-inc/1173319) which was closed as not-a-bug with instruction to use the flag.