# decltype of entity that may be captured: should it yield the type of the entity outside of the lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, decltype-auto

Consider this simple self-contained code:

```
template<typename T>
void foo();

void bar() {
    int i;
    auto l = [&i]() -> decltype(auto) {
        decltype(auto) x = i;
        foo<decltype(x)>();
        foo<decltype(i)>();
        return static_cast<decltype(i)>(i);
    };
    l();
    foo<decltype(l())>();
}
```

GCC Generates the following:

```
bar():
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    void foo<int&>()
        call    void foo<int>()
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     void foo<int>()
```

Clang Generates the following:

```
bar():                                # @bar()
        push    rax
        call    void foo<int>()
        call    void foo<int>()
        pop     rax
        jmp     void foo<int>()                     # TAILCALL
```

MSVC Generates the following:

```
void bar(void) PROC                                        ; bar, COMDAT
$LN8:
        sub     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        call    void foo<int &>(void)                  ; foo<int &>
        call    void foo<int &>(void)                  ; foo<int &>
        add     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        jmp     void foo<int &>(void)                        ; foo<int &>
void bar(void) ENDP
```

It seems all three compiler disagree. Which one is right and what part of the C++ standard confirms it?

In my mind, `decltype(i)` should always be `int`, and never `int&`, no matter if it is captured or not.

[Obligatory compiler explorer link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G6jdTr579)

Comment: Interesting: `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x),int&>);` passes in gcc but fails in clang and wierdly `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(i),int&>);` fails in gcc and it says that `i` is `int` - even though `x` is `int&` (this is all inside the lambda btw)

Comment: Yeah, I think `x` is supposed to be `int`. I think clang is right, but I need the paragraph from the standard to prove it so I can report a more detailed bug report to microsoft.

Comment: I was expecting `int&` for both but since `clang++` disagrees and `g++` gives this confusing result, I tend to believe you are right. I hope someone clears this up.

Comment: I'm saying that because you can change the type of `decltype(i)` simply by declaring unrelated lines on msvc: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/h86coK3q7 this doesn't make sense in my mind.

Comment: IIRC, there need not be a member of the lambda when captured by reference.  That could be part of why different compilers use different types

Comment: The MSVC part is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71460427/why-do-these-lambda-captured-values-have-different-types. I am not sure about the GCC/Clang difference at the moment.

Comment: It seems the GCC behavior is already reported as bug (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96917).

Comment: MSVC's legacy lambda parser is buggy (see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-lambda?view=msvc-170)). If you use  /Zc:lambda or /std:c++20, you'll get the right result which is consistent with Clang.

Comment: @F.v.S. hmm, thank you. So the only one with a bug is GCC in that case. I'm glad to hear!