# Why lambda capture by value provide reference type in the lambda body

Tags: c++, lambda, variable-types

I was writing some code dependent on type of variable and found out that referenced argument to function captured by value detected as reference type inside lambda body. I checked it with `static_assert` for `std::is_same_v` and `decltype`.
Given code will be successfully compiled, but if I replace `std::is_same_v<decltype(a),Loud&>` to `std::is_same_v<decltype(a),Loud>`, the `static_assert` will fail.

```
void foo(Loud& a) {
    auto lamb = [a]() {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(a),Loud&>);
    };
}
```

I expected that `decltype(a)` is equal to `Loud`, because it was copied.

Then I tried to check was it really copied with given code:

```
class Loud{
public:
    Loud() {
        cout << "ctor" << endl;
    }
    
    Loud(Loud& other) {
        cout << "copy ctor" << endl;
    }
};

void foo(Loud& a) {
    auto lamb = [a]() {
        static_assert(is_same_v<decltype(a),Loud&>);
    };
}

int main()
{
    Loud a;
    foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

And I found that it was copied because I had `copy ctor` line in my output.

After all of this I continued to experiment and was suprised that following code was successfully compiled

```
void foo(Loud& a) {
    Loud b;
    auto lamb = [a, b]() {
        static_assert(is_same_v<decltype(a),Loud&>);
        static_assert(is_same_v<decltype(b),Loud>);
    };
}
```

Finally I am totally confused with this behavior. Can you please explain me what is going on here?

Comment: `decltype` has a custom behavior when given a variable name (as opposed to any other expression), and a part of that behavior is ignoring lambda captures. `decltype((a))` would avoid this special case and respect the capture, but it would return `const Loud &`, since for non-variables it artificially appends `&`/`&&`/` ` to indicate the value category of the expression, and yours is an lvalue.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Lambda capture reference by copy and decltype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32894748/580083).

Comment: See [What is decltype and how is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815221/what-is-decltype-and-how-is-it-used). It explains what decltype does.

Comment: When you say `decltype(a)` in the body of the lambda, the `a` is not the captured copy of the variable, but the original variable (function parameter).